# Expand data in excel

Tags: excel

I want to expand the value below. Anyone have a good formula or process, format I want to get to is 000.000.000.000 and could be more or less periods such as 000.000.000.

(Starting) Cell A2

```
1.6.129.5
```

(Formula) Cell B2

```
001.006.129.005
```

*I am using excel 2016

Thank you!

Comment: Is it always 4 numeric characters delimited by period like `N.N.N.N`?

Comment: What version of Excel?

Comment: A simple but inelegant formula could be created using four basic text parsing formulas stitched together. Personally, I'd write a UDF using split to keep the worksheet neat and tidy.

Comment: Always delimited by period, but not always 4 numeric periods. Also I am on excel 2016.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Office 365 Excel then you can use TEXTJOIN as an array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(".",TRUE,TEXT(--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""))+1))-1)*99+1,99)),"000"))
```

Being an Array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

---

If you do not have Office 365 then you will need to parse each part individually:

```
=MID(
            IF(ISNUMBER(--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",REPT(" ",99)),1,99))),"." & TEXT(--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",REPT(" ",99)),1,99)),"000"),"") &
            IF(ISNUMBER(--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",REPT(" ",99)),99,99))),"." & TEXT(--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",REPT(" ",99)),99,99)),"000"),"") &
            IF(ISNUMBER(--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",REPT(" ",99)),198,99))),"." & TEXT(--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",REPT(" ",99)),198,99)),"000"),"") &
            IF(ISNUMBER(--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",REPT(" ",99)),297,99))),"." & TEXT(--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",REPT(" ",99)),297,99)),"000"),"") &
            IF(ISNUMBER(--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",REPT(" ",99)),396,99))),"." & TEXT(--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",REPT(" ",99)),396,99)),"000"),"")
,2,99)
```

You will need to add a new IF for as many as parts as can be, this one assumes the max number of parts to be 5.

[image]

---

Or you can use this UDF which splits on the provided delimiter then formats each part with the provided number format and puts it back together:

```
Function MyFormat(str As String, delim As String, pat As String) As String
Dim strArr() As String
strArr = Split(str, delim)

Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(strArr) To UBound(strArr)
    If IsNumeric(strArr(i)) Then
        strArr(i) = Format(Val(strArr(i)), pat)
    End If
Next i
MyFormat = Join(strArr, delim)
End Function
```

then you would use it from the worksheet with:

```
=MyFormat(A1,".","000")
```

[image]

Comment: I am using excel 2016

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a User Defined Function that should take care of any length. This should be pasted into a standard public module code sheet (Alt+F11, Insert, Module).

```
Option Explicit

Function paddZeroes(str As String, _
                    Optional padding As Long = 3)
    Dim i As Long, tmp As Variant

    tmp = Split(str, Chr(46))

    For i = LBound(tmp) To UBound(tmp)
        tmp(i) = Format(CLng(tmp(i)), String(padding, "0"))
    Next i

    paddZeroes = Join(tmp, Chr(46))

End Function
```

[image]